# Coupled second order differential equations for radial field

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, celestial-mechanics

I have the following coupled differential equations: $$m\ddot x=-\frac{x}{(x^2+y^2)^{3/2}}$$ $$m\ddot y=-\frac{y}{(x^2+y^2)^{3/2}}$$
I've tried defining  $\eta=x+iy$ and multiplying the equation of $m\ddot y$ by $i$ but this didn't work due to the $x^2+y^2$ on the bottom splitting into $(x+iy)(x-iy)$. The $(x^2+y^2)^{3/2}$ on the bottom makes it seem like there isn't a nice analytic solution to this, however it just describes a radial field, so with intial velocity of $0$ it should come out with a straight line.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Have you tried writing $x=r(t)\cos(\theta(t))$ and $y = r(t)\sin(\theta(t))$?

Comment: @user14717 Thanks, I'll have a think about how to work it round this way

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the motion of a mass $m$ in the gravitational potential $-\frac1{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$. Thus a constant of motion is the energy
$$
E(x,\dot x)=\frac m2 (\dot x^2+\dot y^2)-\frac1{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}=const.
$$
A second constant is obtained from
$$
x\ddot y-y\ddot x=0\implies x\dot y-y\dot x=const.
$$

As is classical, the solutions are the Kepler ellipses.

---

Inserting polar coordinates leads to
$$
r^2\dot \phi=L
$$
and
\begin{align}
E&=\frac{m}2(\dot r^2+r^2\dot\phi^2)-\frac1r
=\frac{m}2\left(\dot r^2+\frac{L^2}{r^2}-\frac2{mr}\right)
\\&=\frac{m}2\left(\dot r^2+\left(\frac{L}{r}-\frac1{mL}\right)^2\right)-\frac1{2mL^2}
\end{align}
which allows to reduce by one dimension by inserting a circle parametrization [and so on](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4033996/developing-keplers-first-law).

Comment: Thanks, never thought of it in terms of energy.

Comment: This seems like it would work for all conservative fields. Is this true?

Comment: The first part yes, that works for all Hamilton systems. For the preservation of angular momentum you need radial symmetry, see Noether theorem for generalization to other symmetries.