# Equation of Motion for a Point Vortex System. Need Help Solving 4 Simultaneous ODEs

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, systems-of-equations, fluid-dynamics

**Background and Statement of the Problem**

We consider the problem in $\mathbb{R^2}.$ As the title states, we are interested in the following equation involving the Hamiltonian of the point vortex system, $H^{2,\Omega},$ and the positions of a pair of point vortices in Lagrangian coordinate, $x_1(t)$ and $x_2(t).$

$$\Omega_j \frac{\text{d}x_j}{\text{d}t} = J\nabla_jH^{2,\Omega} (x_j). \tag{1} \label{1}$$

Here, $x_j = \begin{bmatrix} x_{j,1} \\ x_{j,2}\end{bmatrix},$ for $j=1,2.$
$J = 
\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ -1 & 0
\end{bmatrix}$
, and
$\nabla_j =
\begin{bmatrix} \partial_{x_{j,1}} \\ \partial_{x_{j,2}}
\end{bmatrix}.$

The Hamiltonian for the system is given by the following formula:

$$H^{2,\Omega}(x_j) = \frac{1}{2} \sum^{2}_{\begin{matrix}k,l=1 \\ k \neq l\end{matrix}} 
\Omega_k \Omega_l G(x_{j,k} , x_{j,l}),
$$

where $G(x_{j,1} , x_{j,2}) = \frac{1}{2\pi} \ln| x_{j,1} - x_{j,2} |^{-1}$ is just the Green's function for the Laplace Equation in the whole space.

We set the constants $\Omega_i$ for this problem as follows, $\Omega_1 = \pm \Omega_2 = 1. $ Thus the Hamiltonian simplifies to the Green's function.

$$H^{2,\Omega}(x_j) = \frac{1}{2\pi} \ln| x_{j,1} - x_{j,2} |^{-1}.
$$

We can then can rewrite \eqref{1} as the following pair of vector equations:

\begin{align}
\frac{\text{d} x_1}{\text{d}t} = \pm J \nabla_1 \Big{(} \frac{1}{2\pi} \ln|x_1 - x_2|^{-1} \Big{)}, \\
\frac{\text{d} x_2}{\text{d}t} = J \nabla_2 \Big{(} \frac{1}{2\pi} \ln|x_1 - x_2|^{-1} \Big{)}.
\end{align}

**My Work**

The spatial derivative on the right hand side serves only to rewrite the log function into a fraction involving absolute values. We're left with a system of 4 ODEs with respect to the time variable, which are written as follows:

$$ \begin{align} \frac{\text{d} x_{1,1}}{\text{d}t} & = \pm \Big{(} -\frac{1}{2\pi} \frac{(x_{1,2} - x_{2,2})}{|x_1 - x_2|^2} \Big{)} \\
\frac{\text{d} x_{1,2}}{\text{d}t} & = \pm \Big{(} \frac{1}{2\pi} \frac{(x_{1,1} - x_{2,1})}{|x_1 - x_2|^2} \Big{)} \\
\frac{\text{d} x_{2,1}}{\text{d}t} & = \Big{(} \frac{1}{2\pi} \frac{(x_{1,2} - x_{2,2})}{|x_1 - x_2|^2} \Big{)} \\
\frac{\text{d} x_{2,2}}{\text{d}t} & = \Big{(} -\frac{1}{2\pi} \frac{(x_{1,1} - x_{2,1})}{|x_1 - x_2|^2} \Big{)}.
\end{align}$$

I have never come across a system of ODEs such as this before, and am at a complete loss as to how to solve them. Any hints or references to texts with this or a similar problem are very much appreciated. Thank you.

**Edit 1.**

The above equations are perhaps better represnted in the following vector form:

$$ \begin{align}
\frac{\text{d} x_{1}}{\text{d}t} & = \pm \Big{(} - J \frac{x_1 - x_2}{|x_1 - x_2|^2} \Big{)}. \\
\frac{\text{d} x_{2}}{\text{d}t} & = \pm \Big{(}  J \frac{x_1 - x_2}{|x_1 - x_2|^2} \Big{)}.
 \end{align} $$

It is then worth noting the main differences between the plus and minus cases for $x_1$. In the plus case, we get

$$ \frac{\text{d} x_{1}}{\text{d}t} + \frac{\text{d} x_{2}}{\text{d}t} = 0,  $$

which I believe corresponds to the vortices revolving together around some centre. In the minus case, we get

$$ \frac{\text{d} x_{1}}{\text{d}t} - \frac{\text{d} x_{2}}{\text{d}t} = 0,  $$

where the two point vortices travel parallel to each other.

Comment: Nice problem, I have a couple of issues at the outset. the line after your "\eqref" you have a factor on $-1$ against $H^{2, \Omega}$ and I initially thought this was down to multiplying by $J$ but you still have $J$ outside the del operator. Also then the two equations you express are both $\mathrm{d} x_1/\mathrm{d}t$'s.

Comment: The main trick is that the angular momentum is constant, that is, Kepler's 2nd law. A minor point is that you can transform to barycentric coordinates, reducing the dimension. See the first half of my answer to https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4033996/developing-keplers-first-law

Comment: @fundamentalform Thank you very much. I will fix both of these now.

Comment: @LutzLehmann Thank you for your response. I see that there is some mention of this in my class notes. I will reread those and also check the answer you linked!