A very interesting problem that from equations to geometry
Qusetion: Assume $x_i(t)\in\mathbb{R}^2$,
\begin{split}
&dx_i(t)=\sum_{j=1,j\not=i}^N\frac1N\nabla^\perp\ln||x_i(t)-x_j(t)||dt=\sum_{j=1,j\not=i}^N\frac1N\frac{(x_i(t)-x_j(t))^\perp}{||x_i(t)-x_j(t)||^2},i=1,\cdots,N\\
&x_i(0)\not=\vec{0}\\
\end{split}
where $(a,b)^\perp=(-b,a),||(a,b)||^2=a^2+b^2.$
Prove there exists $\delta>0$ s.t. $\widetilde{x}_i(t)\in\mathbb{R}^2\backslash B(0,\delta),\forall t\in [0,+\infty)$, where $\widetilde{x}_i(t)=x_i(t)-m(t),m(t)=\frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^Nx_i$.
The following is my idea:
First, for simplicity, according to the position of the points at t=0, rename the points clockwise to $\widetilde{x}_1,\cdots,\widetilde{x}_N$. It is not hard to get:
$$
\sum_{i=1}^N||\widetilde{x}_i||^2\equiv C_1\text{ , }
\frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^N\widetilde{x}_i\equiv C_2\text{ , }\sum_{cyc}=\sum_{1\le i<j\le N}||\widetilde{x}_i-\widetilde{x}_j||^2\equiv C_3
$$
Then I want to use this 3 properties to prove the question but failed when $N=4$, not even $N=5,6\cdots$. So I want your advice how to do it, please……
Maybe you feel confuesd about these properties, I can prove the hardest third property for you:
\begin{split}
\sum_{cyc}=(N-1)\sum_{i=1}^N||\widetilde{x}_i||^2-2\sum_{1\le i<j\le N}\widetilde{x}_i\cdot \widetilde{x}_{j}
=(N-1)C-2\sum_{1\le i<j\le N}\widetilde{x}_i\cdot \widetilde{x}_{j}\\
\end{split}
\begin{split}
\frac{d\sum_{cyc}}{dt}
=&-2\sum_{1\le i<j\le N}(\widetilde{x}_i'\cdot \widetilde{x}_j+\widetilde{x}_i\cdot \widetilde{x}_j')\\
\end{split}
Now to get further:
\begin{split}
\sum_{1\le i<j\le N}(\widetilde{x}_i'\cdot \widetilde{x}_j+\widetilde{x}_i\cdot \widetilde{x}_j')
=\sum_{1\le i<j\le N}
\left(
\sum_{k=1,k\not=i}^N\frac1N\nabla^\perp\ln||\widetilde x_i-\widetilde x_k||\cdot \widetilde{x}_j+
\widetilde{x}_i\cdot \sum_{k=1,k\not=j}^N\frac1N\nabla^\perp\ln||\widetilde x_j-\widetilde x_k||
\right)
\end{split}
The formula above looks scared. But there are just some products in the above formula. Maybe we need fix $i=i_0$ and $j=j_0$ to discuss the coefficient of $\nabla^\perp\ln||\widetilde x_i-\widetilde x_j||$. To simplify the notation, I fix $i=3,j=6$ and it is the same with other numbers. Then we will discuss it by extracting the product containing $\ln||\widetilde x_3-\widetilde x_6||$:
case 1: when $i=1,2,j=3$: get $\frac1N\widetilde{x}_{i}\cdot\ln||\widetilde{x}_{3}-\widetilde{x}_{6}||$ from $\widetilde{x}_i\cdot \sum_{k=1,k\not=j}^N\frac1N\nabla^\perp\ln||\widetilde x_j-\widetilde x_k||$;
case 2: when $i=1,2,j=6$: get $\frac1N\widetilde{x}_{i}\cdot\ln||\widetilde{x}_{6}-\widetilde{x}_{3}||$ from $\widetilde{x}_i\cdot \sum_{k=1,k\not=j}^N\frac1N\nabla^\perp\ln||\widetilde x_j-\widetilde x_k||$;
case 3: when $i=3,j\not=6$: get $\frac1N\ln||\widetilde{x}_{3}-\widetilde{x}_{6}||\cdot\widetilde{x}_{j}$ from $\sum_{k=1,k\not=i}^N\frac1N\nabla^\perp\ln||\widetilde x_i-\widetilde x_k||\cdot\widetilde{x}_{j}$;
case 4: when $i=3,j=6$: get $\frac1N\ln||\widetilde{x}_{3}-\widetilde{x}_{6}||\cdot\widetilde{x}_{6}$ and $\widetilde{x}_{3}\cdot\frac1N\ln||\widetilde{x}_{6}-\widetilde{x}_{3}||$;
case 5: when $i=4,5,j=6$: get $\frac1N\widetilde{x}_{i}\cdot\ln||\widetilde{x}_{6}-\widetilde{x}_{3}||$ from $\widetilde{x}_i\cdot \sum_{k=1,k\not=j}^N\frac1N\nabla^\perp\ln||\widetilde x_j-\widetilde x_k||$;
case 6: when $i=6,j=7,\cdots,N$: get $\frac1N\ln||\widetilde{x}_{6}-\widetilde{x}_{3}||\cdot\widetilde{x}_{j}$ from $ \sum_{k=1,k\not=i}^N\frac1N\nabla^\perp\ln||\widetilde x_i-\widetilde x_k||\cdot\widetilde{x}_j$.
So the coefficient of $\nabla^\perp\ln||\widetilde{x}_{3}-\widetilde{x}_{6}||$ is $(\widetilde{x}_1+\widetilde{x}_2)+(-\widetilde{x}_1-\widetilde{x}_2)+(\sum_{4\le i\le N,i\not=6}\widetilde{x}_i)+(\widetilde{x}_6-\widetilde{x}_3)+(-\widetilde{x}_4-\widetilde{x}_5)+(-\sum_{7\le i\le N}\widetilde{x}_i)=\widetilde{x}_6-\widetilde{x}_3$. Obviously $(\widetilde{x}_6-\widetilde{x}_3)\nabla^\perp\ln||\widetilde{x}_{3}-\widetilde{x}_{6}||=0$.
As what I said previously, other numbers are the same. Therefore,
$$
\sum_{1\le i<j\le N}(\widetilde{x}_i'\cdot \widetilde{x}_j+\widetilde{x}_i\cdot \widetilde{x}_j')
=0\Rightarrow \sum_{cyc}=\sum_{1\le i<j\le N}||\widetilde{x}_i-\widetilde{x}_j||^2\equiv C_3
$$
Maybe I need to analyse from the equation rather than geometry. I tried but failed:
\begin{split}
x_i(t)=&x_i(0)+\int_0^t\sum_{j=1,j\not=i}^N\frac1N\nabla^\perp\ln||\widetilde x_i(s)-\widetilde x_j(s)||ds\\
=&x_i(0)+\int_0^t\sum_{j=1,j\not=i}^N\frac{(\widetilde x_i-\widetilde x_j)^\perp}{N||\widetilde x_i-\widetilde x_j||^2}ds\\
\le& x_i(0)+\int_0^t\sum_{j=1,j\not=i}^N\frac{1}{N||\widetilde x_i-\widetilde x_j||}ds\\
\ge& x_i(0)+\int_0^t\frac{(N-1)^2}{N\sum_{j=1,j\not=i}^N||\widetilde x_i-\widetilde x_j||}ds\\
\ge& x_i(0)+\int_0^t\frac{(N-1)^2}{N\sum_{j=1,j\not=i}^N\frac{||\widetilde x_i-\widetilde x_j||^2+1}{2}}ds\\
\ge& x_i(0)+\int_0^t\frac{2(N-1)^2}{N(C_3+N-1))}ds\\
\ge& x_i(0)+\frac{2(N-1)^2}{N(C_3+N-1))}t\\
\end{split}
$$
||x_i(t)||^2=||x_i(0)||^2+||\int_0^t\sum_{j=1,j\not=i}^N\frac1N\frac{(\widetilde x_i-\widetilde x_j)^\perp}{||\widetilde x_i-\widetilde x_j||^2}ds||^2+2x_i(0)\cdot\int_0^t\sum_{j=1,j\not=i}^N\frac1N\frac{(\widetilde x_i-\widetilde x_j)^\perp}{||\widetilde x_i-\widetilde x_j||^2}ds
$$

It would be nice to have the context of the problem. What is this for?

Just study the movement and trajectory of points on a plane. You can imagine these points as any physical quantity with physical meaning.

Ok, but this interpretation is possible for any assumed set of ODE of 2N unknowns, so you have N trajectories in the plane. Why is this particular one "interesting"? After all you use this adjective in the title, so there must be something particular and interesting about this problem. Maybe you can link a reference to a paper or book: this is probably a well known and widely studied problem. I suspect that  this is the motion of point vortices https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4167928/532409

Oh, thanks for your help. From my point of view, this equations has very clear geometric meaning. After you provide this link, we can see this particals as celestial body or point vortices, which further illustrates the applicability of this movement trajectory.

And what is this very clear geometric meaning? Note that celestial bodies move in a different way (gravity is central force, while for vortices you have a force the resembles the magnetic Lorenz force).

For me, the trajectory can have those three constants and I already have a certain feeling in geometry. My physics is not very good. I think you are right, these particles can not be celestial bodies. Can you tell me the name of the force between the vortices? I hope to have a deeper understanding.

There is no specific name in Physics for the force between these vortices. However, it is the same force as the Lorentz force between wires carrying currents. If the wires are straight and parallel and you just consider their positions in the orthogonal plane, then you have the same equations of motion as the point vortices in the plane.

Thank you, after I asked my teacher, this is exactly point vortices.

I'm from Central Asia. I consider this problem interesting. The problem involves solving a system of ordinary differential equations (ODEs) for the motion of a point vortex system in two-dimensional space (R2). The equations are derived from the Hamiltonian of the system, which is a function of the vortex strengths (Ω) and the positions of the vortices in Lagrangian coordinates (x1(t) and x2(t)).
The Hamiltonian is given by the formula:
$$H_{2, \Omega}\left(x_{j}\right)=\frac{1}{2} \sum_{k, l=1}^{2} \Omega_{k} \Omega_{l} G\left(x_{j, k}, x_{j, l}\right)$$
where G is the Green's function for the Laplace equation in the whole space, defined as:
$$G\left(x_{j, 1}, x_{j, 2}\right)=\frac{1}{2 \pi} \ln \left|x_{j, 1}-x_{j, 2}\right|-1$$
For this problem, the vortex strengths are set such that Ω1 = ±Ω2 = 1, which simplifies the Hamiltonian to the Green's function:
$$H_{2, \Omega}\left(x_{j}\right)=\frac{1}{2 \pi} \ln \left|x_{j, 1}-x_{j, 2}\right|-1$$
The equations of motion can be rewritten as a pair of vector equations:
$$\frac{d x_{1}}{d t}= \pm\left(-J \nabla_{1}\left(\frac{1}{2 \pi} \ln \left|x_{1}-x_{2}\right|-1\right)\right), \frac{d x_{2}}{d t}=J \nabla_{2}\left(\frac{1}{2 \pi} \ln \left|x_{1}-x_{2}\right|-1\right)$$
The spatial derivatives on the right-hand side of these equations can be computed to express the logarithmic function as a fraction involving absolute values, resulting in a system of four ODEs with respect to the time variable.
You've already taken steps to compute these derivatives and has arrived at the following system of ODEs:
$$\begin{array}{l}
\frac{d x_{1,1}}{d t}= \pm\left(-\frac{1}{2 \pi}\left(x_{1,2}-x_{2,2}\right)\left|x_{1}-x_{2}\right|^{2}\right), \frac{d x_{1,2}}{d t}= \pm\left(\frac{1}{2 \pi}\left(x_{1,1}-x_{2,1}\right)\left|x_{1}-x_{2}\right|^{2}\right) \\
\frac{d x_{2,1}}{d t}=\left(\frac{1}{2 \pi}\left(x_{1,2}-x_{2,2}\right)\left|x_{1}-x_{2}\right|^{2}\right), \frac{d x_{2,2}}{d t}=\left(-\frac{1}{2 \pi}\left(x_{1,1}-x_{2,1}\right)\left|x_{1}-x_{2}\right|^{2}\right)
\end{array}$$
One approach to solving this system is to use numerical integration methods, such as Runge-Kutta methods, which are widely implemented in various computational software. These methods provide an approximate solution to the system of ODEs by discretizing time and iteratively updating the positions of the vortices.
Another approach is to look for invariants or symmetries in the system that might simplify the equations. For instance, the user has observed that for the plus and minus cases, there are certain relationships between the time derivatives of x1 and x2 that could potentially be exploited to simplify the system.
In terms of references, textbooks on fluid dynamics or mathematical physics that cover vortex dynamics or Hamiltonian systems might provide insights or methods applicable to this problem. Specific texts that cover point vortex dynamics or the equations of motion for vortices could be particularly helpful.
I think this problem is a classic in the field and has been studied extensively. I have some books about this field.If you're interested, you can send me a contact approach and I can lend them to you.
Best regards.
